# Perl pie alternative

Tags: perl, git

Running on Cygwin, I cannot easily use `perl -pi -e` because it will always produce `.bak` files even though I don't want them. I wrote this script below to emulate `perl -pi -e` behavior and unlink the backup files after processing.

Also I wanted to simplify the call of the script. Instead of:

```
$ git ls-files | xargs perl -pi -e s/foo/bar/
```

I rather prefer to write

```
$ git ls-files | pie s/foo/bar
```

Although this program is not aimed to be particularly used with Git, with this alias `pie="!git ls-files | pie"` it becomes

```
$ git pie s/foo/bar
```

I feel this script can be simplified and the performances could be slightly improved. The question is how.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

my $re = shift @ARGV;
@ARGV  = split(/\n/, do {local $/; <stdin>}) if @ARGV eq 0;

for my $file (@ARGV) {
    next unless -f $file;
    if (-f "$file.bak") {
        warn "[Warning] Backup file already exists and is been used by pie";
    }
    open my $fh,  "<",  $file;
    open my $tmp, ">", "$file.bak";
    while (<$fh>) {
        eval($re);
    } continue { print $tmp $_ }
    close $tmp;
    close $fh;
    move "$file.bak", $file;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just delete `.bak` files created by `perl -i.bak -pe..`?

Comment: @mpapec It is basically what I do! The idea is to shorten the writing as well. With this I can avoid using `xargs`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is a solution with no additional modules, moving `eval` out of the loop, and with few additional checks.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$^I = '.bak';
my $re = shift @ARGV or die "Nothing to do..";
$re = eval "sub{ $re }" or die "Incorrect expression..";

chomp(@ARGV  = <STDIN>) if !@ARGV;
@ARGV = grep {
  warn "[Warning] Backup file already exists and is been used by pie"
    if -f "$_$^I";
  -f $_;
}
@ARGV;

my @bak = map "$_$^I", @ARGV;
while (<>) {
  $re->();
  print;
}
unlink(@bak);
```